# Phantom Links in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I’m new to this forum and was looking for help with what appears to be a phantom link in my workbook. To isolate the issue, in a Saved As version, I began deleting worksheets until the link disappeared. Here is where it gets strange. I’ve isolated the problem to two sheets. It is only when I delete both sheets that the link disappears. Deleting one or the other, regardless of order, doesn’t eliminate the link. Stranger still, I tried to isolate the issue on those sheets by deleting all controls, macros, data validation, filters, and formulas – each time saving the file and reopening – but still getting the link. It is only when I select all rows and columns and Delete that the issue goes away. This must be done in both sheets. I’m out of ideas on how to troubleshoot this further and was hoping for guidance on some next steps. Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: This might help if i'm understanding this issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/break-a-link-to-an-external-reference-in-excel-f1ca8b08-4f24-4af6-92e5-f4fdb1442748

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was able to solve this but deleting all Named objects.

Thank you